# Is there a way to achieve the same behavior of sending notifications as email notifications using GitHub API?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I'm building a Telegram bot for myself that should send to me notifications when I get any. I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as GitHub's email notifications. The problem is that I'm not sure if it's even possible. I'm working with GitHub API for few days straight trying to solve this issue but I still have no idea how to do it. It's like GitHub API doesn't provide enough information about the notification.

For example, it provides field "reason", which describes why I got this notification but how to understand what this notification is about? Like, if I was assigned to the issue or pull request (right now it seems like notifications are the same whether I got assigned to the issue or got a new message in the assigned issue), or got a new message in a watching issue/pull request or anything else.